# How to unset session in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am using session in my magento custom module.Below is my code

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));

$session->setData("day_filter", 'weeks');
$session->setData("days", '5');          
$session->setData("next_delivery_date", '2012-05-12');
```

The above code is working fine, but now i want to unset or destroy all the value? Can you please provide me the solution how to unset all set values?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are several ways to unset session variables in Magento.  Most of these (not all) are defined in `Varien_Object` and so are avialable to all objects in Magento that extend it.

**unsetData:**

```
    $session->unsetData('day_filter');
    $session->unsetData('days');
    $session->unsetData('next_delivery_date');
```

**uns** (which will be marginally slower and ultimately executes unsetData anyway):

```
   $session->unsDayFilter();
   $session->unsDays();
   $session->unsNextDeliveryDate();
```

**getData**

Not a mistake! A relatively unkown method exists in `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien`.  The getData method in this class contains an optional boolean second parameter which if passed true will clear the variable while returning it.

So `$session->getData('day_filter', true);` would return the session variable day_filter and also clear it from the session at the same time.

**Set to null**:

```
   $session->setData('day_filter', NULL);
   $session->setData('days', NULL);
   $session->setData('next_delivery_date', NULL);
```

**unsetAll | clear**

Finally you could use the nuclear option  (**BEWARE:** This will unset **ALL DATA** in the session, not just the data you have added):

`$session->unsetAll();` or `$session->clear();` (both aliases of each other)